# Como puedo validar si un rango de fechas pasa por cierta hora

Tags: javascript

me podrías ayudar... digamos que tengo el siguiente código:

```
var produccion_inicio = new Date('2022-12-30 11:00:00');
var produccion_fin = new Date('2022-12-30 13:00:00');
var operador_descanso_inicio = 12:00;
var operador_descanso_fin = 12:30;
```

Y quiero hacer lo siguiente:

- Si en el inter de producción se atraviesa el descanso del operador, entonces se debe agregar media hora a la fecha de finalización de la producción.

Comment: Aunque ya tenga una respuesta válida y el código esté correctamente formateado, votaré por cerrar esta pregunta porque muestra cero esfuerzo del lado del usuario y ya existen en el sitio muchas otras relacionadas con el cálculo de fechas. Parece más bien "háganme la tarea"

Answer (score 1):

Para compararlo, tus variables `operador_descanso_inicio` y `operador_descanso_fin` tendría que ser también de objeto `Date()`, por ejemplo así:

```
var operador_descanso_inicio = new Date('2022-12-30 12:00:00');
var operador_descanso_fin = new Date('2022-12-30 12:30:00');
```

Y para obtener el tiempo, sería con:

```
produccion_inicio.getTime()...
```

Y ya con esto que obtienes, validas tus fechas, así:

```js
var produccion_inicio = new Date('2022-12-30 11:00:00');
var produccion_fin = new Date('2022-12-30 13:00:00');
var operador_descanso_inicio = new Date('2022-12-30 12:00:00');
var operador_descanso_fin = new Date('2022-12-30 12:30:00');

produccion_inicio.getTime() < operador_descanso_inicio.getTime() && produccion_fin.getTime() > operador_descanso_fin.getTime() ? 
    produccion_fin.setMinutes(produccion_fin.getMinutes() + 30) : 
    produccion_fin.setMinutes(produccion_fin.getMinutes() + 0);

console.log(produccion_fin.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Por que te da 16:30 en vez de 13:30 ??

Comment: Definitivamente el timezone. A mi me resulta "2022-12-30T19:30:00.000Z".

Comment: Y a mí "2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z", aunque en mi compilador me dice el resultado correcto -> "Fri Dec 30 2022 13:30:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Perú)", con `.toLocaleString()` se arreglaría, depende a los casos.

Comment: Por cierto... Por qué estás contestando una pregunta con cero esfuerzo?

Comment: @Arriel Tiene razón, solo me pareció interesante la pregunta, olvidé tomar en cuenta eso, lo siento.